# Different color schemes for winform with materialdesign C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using MaterialSkin in my winform application. I want different color schemes for two forms, but when I open second form - style changes for both of them.
The code of first(main) form:

```
public partial class Form1 : MaterialForm
{
    private readonly MaterialSkinManager materialSkinManager  = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Create a material theme manager and add the form to manage (this)
        materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
        materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;

        // Configure color schema
        materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(
            Primary.BlueGrey800, Primary.BlueGrey900,
            Primary.BlueGrey500, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);
    }

    private void materialRaisedButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        if(form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OK");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

The code of second form:

```
public partial class Form2 : MaterialForm
{
    private readonly MaterialSkinManager materialSkinManager2 = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        materialSkinManager2.AddFormToManage(this);

        // Configure color schema
        materialSkinManager2.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(
            Primary.DeepOrange300, Primary.BlueGrey900,
            Primary.BlueGrey500, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

The result of this code is:
[image]
[image]

Help me please

Comment: Looks like this is not a use case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaterialSkinManager` is a singleton , which means that there is only one instance of it. So when you change the color scheme in your second window it also changes the color scheme of the first window.

I looked at the code on GitHub and I don't think that two different schemes is supported, which makes sense, because you want your UI to look consistent.